# SELECT NON LOCKED ROWS with ORACLE "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED" in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

I have to pick one record which is not locked with FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED.

When I search for this I found there is a solution in 12C called FETCH. But I am using Oracle 11g and I just need to get one record out of non-locked records for update.

```
select * from t1 
where record_status = 'ACTIVE' 
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

Above query locked all other records which are not locked. Please suggest a solution which can be used to lock only one record and fetch that one for update in oracle 11g.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use rownum or some identifier to lock only specific rows of your need.

Let's look at the following example:

```
-- session1

SQL> create table t1(id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values(1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 values(2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 values(3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 values(4);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t1 where id = 2 for update skip locked;

        ID
----------
         2



-- Session 2

SQL> select * from t1 where rownum <= 1 for update skip locked;

        ID
----------
         1



-- Session 3

SQL> select * from t1 for update skip locked;

        ID
----------
         3
         4
```

Hope this will clear the things.

And also, Please note that Oracle created "skip locked" for their internal use in AQ and afterward they have made it available for public use.
Oracle uses it for their internal operations and it works exactly the way for which it was implemented for Oracle's need which we don't know, so we usually misuse it unknowingly.

Comment: Actually, I have a record pool where I need to pick only one record at a time for update randomly. So we can not use any specific id as you mentioned.  Are there any way to identify blocked rows in Oracle. Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: You can use the rownum as mentioned in the Session 2 query which will give only one record randomly(Forget about session1 and session 3 queries. I have used them for better understanding). 

You can use the record for an update which will be returned by session 2 query.-- I think this will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

FOR 
    cur IN (select rowid from mwt_user_wallet where wallet_type = 'MCA') 
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      select rowid into id from MWT_USER_WALLET where rowid = cur.rowid for update nowait;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN v_resourcr_busy THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('record locked');
    END;
  END LOOP;

Can we use this to identify non-locked rows?